How do I solve Inconsistent accessibility parameter in ASP .NET Integration testing?
I am trying to make clean integration tests for ASP .NET WebApi.
This is the webapplication factory class.
The program class its using in the extend is an internal from the API project. (Done with InternalsVisibleTo)
internal class DozerWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    //Omitted not useful
}

In tests I can do this:
public class QuotesControllerTests
{

    private readonly DozerWebApplicationFactory _application;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public QuotesControllerTests()
    {
        // Arrange/Setup
        _application = new DozerWebApplicationFactory();
        _httpClient = _application.CreateClient();
    }


}

But I would like to do this using the IClassFixture class:
public class QuotesControllerTests : IClassFixture<DozerWebApplicationFactory>
{

    private readonly DozerWebApplicationFactory _application;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public QuotesControllerTests(DozerWebApplicationFactory application)
    {
        // It doesn't work because this constructor is public (tests need to be public) but the Factory is internal due to program being internal as stated above.
        _application = application;
        _httpClient = _application.CreateClient();
    }


}

However this last approach does not because this constructor is public (tests need to be public) but the Factory is internal due to program being internal as stated above.

CS0051    Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'DozerWebApplicationFactory' is less accessible than method 'QuotesControllerTests.QuotesControllerTests(DozerWebApplicationFactory)'

What can I do to make this work with IClassFixture?

Even leaving the constructor aside, the fact that it's a public generic class with an internal type argument would cause this problem, I suspect. Does DozerWebApplicationFactory have to be internal? Could you possibly introduce a public class in your test project that acts as a sort of proxy/holder for a DozerWebApplicationFactory?

@JonSkeet Yes, DozerWebApplicationFactory  has to be internal since it uses Program (from other project, with InternalsVisibleTo) : DozerWebApplicationFactory  : WebApplicationFactory<Program> which is internal. I am not sure about the proxy/holder could you give an example?

public class DozerFactoryHolder { internal DozerWebApplicationFactory Factory { get; set; } } for example. Then use DozerFactoryHolder as the type argument and constructor parameter.

@JonSkeet Thanks, this works. Is it considered a good/bad practice though? Also is there any way to omit the get .Factory to get to the actual DozerWebApplicationFactory?

It's a workaround for "I want this to be internal, but want to be able to use it as if it were public". Seems okay to me. As for avoiding the property - you could use an implicit conversion, but that doesn't sound like a good idea to me. (You can still store private readonly DozerWebApplicationFactory _application, using _application = application.Factory; in the constructor. Surely using the property directly once isn't too much of a burden?

@JonSkeet gotcha, thankyou very much for helping me today :)

Will write this up as an answer then.

One option is to create a sort of "holder" in the test project - that can be a public class, but contain a reference to the internal class:
public class DozerFactoryHolder
{
    internal DozerWebApplicationFactory Factory { get; set; }
}

That can then be used as the type argument and constructor parameter:
public class QuotesControllerTests : IClassFixture<DozerFactoryHolder>
{
    private readonly DozerWebApplicationFactory _application;

    public QuotesControllerTests(DozerFactoryHolder holder)
    {
        _application = holder.Factory;
        ...
    }
}

